# How to solve the DE $y'+ky^{1/2}=q(t)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a problem about a tank which is being filled with water and has a small hole at the bottom. I came with the non-linear ordinary differential equation
$$\dfrac{dy}{dt}+k\,y^{1/2}=q(t),\qquad y(0)=y_0$$
where $k>0$ is a constant and $q:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a piecewise continuous function. In order to solve this DE I have tried with the substitutions $y=w^2$ and $y=z^4$ but they don't work. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: @Moo ??? Equation is not linear.

Comment: @Moo, why don't you try it, see if it works, and if it does - post it as an answer?

Comment: divide by y^(1/2) and put y^(1/2)=z.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam: Nice try, but it won't work: how do you perform $\int \dfrac {z'} {\frac q z - k} \ \Bbb d t$? You don't know anything about $q$. My opinion is that the problem is not analytically solvable in general.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam: Your substitution es equivalent to do the substitution $y=w^2$, as I mentioned before, it doesn't work.

Comment: notice that (sqrt(y))'=y'/2sqrt(y)

Comment: @AbdallahHammam: Once you get $2z'+k=\frac{q}{z}$ then... what follows?

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=y^\frac{1}{2}$ ,

Then $y=u^2$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=2u\dfrac{du}{dt}$

$\therefore2u\dfrac{du}{dt}+ku=q(t)$ with $u(0)=\pm\sqrt{y_0}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $u=-\dfrac{kv}{2}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dt}=-\dfrac{k}{2}\dfrac{dv}{dt}$

$\therefore\dfrac{k^2v}{2}\dfrac{dv}{dt}-\dfrac{k^2v}{2}=q(t)$ with $v(0)=\pm\dfrac{2\sqrt{y_0}}{k}$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dt}-v=\dfrac{2q(t)}{k^2}$ with $v(0)=\pm\dfrac{2\sqrt{y_0}}{k}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form.

Please follow the method in https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf or in http://www.iaeng.org/IJAM/issues_v43/issue_3/IJAM_43_3_01.pdf